# Terminal window closes after double clicking executable .sh file in Fedora Linux

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, sh

I have to work on a project in Fedora Linux and I have to type the following very often:

`player map1.cfg &`

I figured out that I can create an executable .sh file and it contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash
player *.cfg &
```

However, when double click on the runmap.sh file it shows me 'Run in Terminal', 'Display', 'Cancel', and 'Run' and when I click 'Run in Terminal' a terminal window opens and closes immediately. If I just hit 'Run' then the .cfg opens but I need the Terminal window to run additional (Java) files.

How can I fix this problem?

Other information:

- I use `*.cfg` because I want to copy and paste the .sh files into other folders that also contain .cfg files such as map2.cfg, map3.cfg, etc.
- It's for a Player/Stage project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run a script from the file manager, the shell that is started isn't interactive. The shell can only read the script file.

To open an interactive shell in addition to the files, you can `exec` the new shell at the end of the script, and use "Run in Terminal":

```
#!/bin/bash
player *.cfg &
exec /bin/bash
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Been googling for a solution for many hours now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well let's look at it this way.

When you run the command in a terminal, the command starts as a child process and is then sent to the background. Once the command finishes it terminates. During the time it is running in the background you can still issue commands because your parent process is the terminal window itself.

When you write a script that issues a command to run in the background it is started, spawns the command as a child to it and then closes because the script has finished.

These are a behavior of the OS and something that really shouldn't change. Essentially what you are therefore asking for is a way for it to run the command quickly for yourself yet still leave a command terminal for you to work with?

1) Why is typing the command such a hassle? Bash and other terminals have a history function for this very reason.

2) Why don't you just call the mini script you wrote from a terminal window whenever you need to call the commands. If you put the script in a folder on your $PATH variable it will be available to you in the terminal at any location.

Comment: I really have to type `player map1.cfg &` many many times. I'd guess over hundreds of times! Every time I open this cfg file I can test if my Java class does what it is supposed to and if not then I have to close the window that the .cfg opened and type it again to test it with my Java class again. That's a lot of typing and having to repeatedly type this when I really just want to get things running is tiring. It saves a lot of time if I only have to make 1 double click + 1 click instead of typing 17 different characters each time (that doesn't even include me mistyping, or forgetting '&').

Comment: Are you using `bash`? Why not just press up? Other terminals (ksh) have history too which you can look up. Alternatively, like I said. Run a terminal and then just call your little script `testMapcfg.sh`. You could run that from anywhere if you modify your $PATH to include the location of the script itself

Comment: I know I can press 'up' but since I will be running Java files afterwards it's a pain to have to search for the command and possible selecting mistyped ones. And sometimes something goes wrong with Player and the Terminal window won't let me type any new commands. So I have to close and re-open. I don't think you understand me :) Perhaps it helps to say that I'm a Mac user and that I want things to be as user-friendly as possible ^.^!

Comment: I think he understands. You should look a bit into the details. Control+C kills your player, if something goes wrong. Actually, you should not even notice this in the bash because you're using "&". There in no need for reopening terminals. Then, you may have a look into projects like Yakuake (which is for KDE, there is similar stuff for Gnome). There are terminals, which you can hide and display just by hitting e.g. F10 - which is wonderful.